# Как вывести элемент из json файла

Tags: python, json

Есть файл `user_info.json`. Его содержимое:

```
[
  {
    "status": 0,
    "moodSticker": {
      "status": 0,
      "iconV2": "ndcsticker://e/e284a2",
    },
    "itemsCount": 7,
    "consecutiveCheckInDays": null,
    "uid": "abb3e859-2df7-4dea-8640-d3a19ccf14d5",
    },
    "pushEnabled": false,
    "membershipStatus": 1,
    "content": "[IMG=MV7]\n\n ZzzzzZzzZz",                      <- Это нужно вывести
    "joinedCount": 5,
    "role": 0,
    "commentsCount": 10027,
    "ndcId": 156542274,
    "createdTime": "2017-12-16T17:05:05Z",
    "extensions": {
      "defaultBubbleId": "abaefd31-23ab-4b5a-983a-582c76767cbf",
      "style": {
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      }
    },
    "visitPrivacy": 1,
    "storiesCount": 0,
    "blogsCount": 16
  }
]
```

Нужно вывести значение ключа `"content"`, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас немного `user_info.json` не правильный - проверьте!

**user_info.json**

```
[
  { 
    "status": 0,
    "moodSticker": {
      "status": 0,
      "iconV2": "ndcsticker://e/e284a2"
    },
    "itemsCount": 7,
    "consecutiveCheckInDays": null,
    "uid": "abb3e859-2df7-4dea-8640-d3a19ccf14d5",
    
    "pushEnabled": false,
    "membershipStatus": 1,
    "content": "[IMG=MV7]\n\n ZzzzzZzzZz",
    "joinedCount": 5,
    "role": 0,
    "commentsCount": 10027,
    "ndcId": 156542274,
    "createdTime": "2017-12-16T17:05:05Z",
    "extensions": {
      "defaultBubbleId": "abaefd31-23ab-4b5a-983a-582c76767cbf",
      "style": {
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      }
    },
    "visitPrivacy": 1,
    "storiesCount": 0,
    "blogsCount": 16
  }
]
```

**main.py**

```
import json

data = open("user_info.json", "r").read()
data = json.loads(data)

print(data[0]["content"])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]